# AWS signed url if the object exists using promises

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, promise

I have a code snippet for generating a signed url. The below `return` statement always returns empty url. Rest of the data is correctly resolved. When I debug I see that the `return callback` gets executed first then the `resolve` part of the `function validSignedURL` gets called.

```
awsHelper
        .s3vldSignedURL(s3Link)
        .then(function(signedURL) {
            data[1].url = signedURL;
            return callback(null, successResponse.getResponse(context, 'OK', data));
        });
```

The `s3vldSignedURL` maps to the function below. Here `s3.headobject` is promise based, used to check if a file exists in s3. I want this function to be generic, so that I can use it to generate a signed url, for any s3object.

```
function validSignedURL(bucket, path) {
console.log("Generating Presigned Link ... ");
const s3 = new aws.S3();

let params = {
    Bucket: bucket,
    Key: path
};

let checkObj = s3.getObject(params);
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    s3.headObject(params).promise()
        .then(function (data) {
            console.log('s3 File exists' + data);
            resolve(getSignedURL(bucket, path));
        }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log('Generating Presigned Link ... Failed' + err);
        resolve('');
    });
});
}
```

The below `function getSignedURL` always returns a  signed url irrespective of the object exists or not.

```
function getSignedURL(bucket, path) {
    console.log("Generating Presigned Link ... ");
    const s3 = new aws.S3();

    let params = {
        Bucket: bucket,
        Key: path
    };

return s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params);
}
```

Also, how can I convert the function call `s3.headObject(params)` to a synchronous call which returns true or false?

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: Also see the [difference between `.then(…, …)` and `.then(…).catch(…)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572), which doesn't however explain why you are seeing `resolve` after the `callback` either (unless that's not your actual code).

Comment: "*How can I convert the function call `s3.headObject(params)` to a synchronous call*" - you cannot. Don't try.

Comment: Another question is, do you really need to know if the object doesn't exist?  Creating a pre-signed URL against a non-existent object **is a valid action** because the pre-signed URL will be valid if the object exists in the future, and will return a `404` error if the pre-signed URL is used used until then (or if the object is never created).

Comment: `validSignedURL` always resolves, sure it resolves `''` on error, but you don't seem to check the resolved value in your code

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, I just assign it to `data[1].url` in the first code block.

Comment: @Bergi Hi, with the promise constructor anti pattern are you asking me to try `return s3.headObject(params).promise()` in place of `return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){` with the call as - `data[1].url = awsHelper. validSignedURL('invndata', s3Link + mapFileName);`  this too behaves in the same nature. The return takes place before.

Comment: @SumitKumarGhosh Yes, that's what you should replace. No, this still returns a promise from `validSignedURL` (you can't prevent that), but then its written properly.

Comment: You solved it ?

Comment: Somehow managed through. I will share the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the complete function definition and calling for AWS signed url if the object exists using promises. If you are using AWS Lambda you need to add s3 permissions.

- If there is no need to validate if the url exists then `getSignedURL` is the function to be used
- If there is a need to check if the object exists then use `validSignedURL` it will return an empty url if not found.

Here is how I implemented it:

```
function getSignedURL(bucket, path) {
    console.log("Generating Presigned Link ... ");

    let params = {
        Bucket: bucket,
        Key: path
    };

    //expires in default 15 mins.
    return s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params);
}

function validSignedURL(bucket, path) {
    console.log("Generating Presigned Link ... ");
    let params = {
        Bucket: bucket,
        Key: path
    };

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        s3.headObject(params).promise()
            .then(function (data) {
                console.log('s3 File exists' + data);
                resolve(getSignedURL(bucket, path));
            }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log('Generating Presigned Link ... Failed' + err);
            resolve('');
        });
    });
}
```

Calling the function and resolving the promise. I have some other fields populated before in `data` which is returned along with the signed url.

```
    validSignedURL(bucketName, s3Link + fileName).then(function(signedURL) {
        data.url = signedURL;
        return callback(null, successResponse.getResponse(context, 'OK', data));
        });
```